# How to identify Ag nanoparticles in a solution?

Tags: biochemistry

Doing an experiment involving the production of Silver nanoparticles using bacterial extracts. The issue is proving that they've been formed.
AgNO3 is added to the solution, and the reduction environment of the bacteria reduces into silver nanoparticles of various size, depending on many factors.
Color change can be seen, and a change in the UV-vis spec also, but beyond that, is there anything else that can be done?
The papers I'm basing this project off of have access to electron microscopes, I don't.
Is there any sort of biological assays that react to metallic silver? or maybe to Ag NPs?
Or anyone have any experience involving biologically producing nanoparticles?
I'll be asking in Chemistry as well for a possible chemical reaction of identify metallic silver.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/the-effects-of-gold-and-silver-nanoparticles-on-an-enzymatic-reaction-between-horseradish-peroxidase-and-tetramethylbenzidine-2167--0501.1000146.php?aid=35278) says that silver nanoparticles enhance the enzymatic reaction that happens in a normal ELISA assay. You should be able to observe a significative shift in UV absorbance comparing your bacteria to a control.

Otherwise, I'd think simply of lysing the bacteria and centrifugating the lysate. I'd expect the pellet to contain nanoparticles and to be somehow different (in color?) from a control pellet.